# Efficient way to retrieve count of number of times a flag set since last n seconds

Tags: c++

I need to track how many times a flag is enabled in last n seconds. Below is the example code I can come up with.StateHandler maintains the value of the flag in active array for last n(360 here) seconds. In my case update function is called from outside every second. So when I need to know how many times it set since last 360 seconds I call getEnabledInLast360Seconds. Is it possible to do it more efficiently like not using an array size of n for booleans ?

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

class StateHandler
{

    bool active[360];
    int index;

public:
    StateHandler() :
        index(0),
        active()
    {
    }

    void update(bool value)
    {
        if (index >= 360)
        {
            index = 0;
        }
        active[index % 360] = value;

        index++;
    }

    int getEnabledInLast360Seconds()
    {
        int value = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 360; i++)
        {
            if (active[i])
            {
                value++;
            }
        }
        return value;
    }
};

int main()
{

    StateHandler handler;
    handler.update(true);
    handler.update(true);
    handler.update(true);
    std::cout << handler.getEnabledInLast360Seconds();
}
```

Comment: why don't you maintain a map of flagcount and time stamp (epoch time). Every time you get an update fill the map. if someone asks you getlast360, retrieve the map values(both time and flagcounts) and subtract the time stamps to get the flag count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of fixing the buffer, you can simply use `std::set<timestamp>` (Or perhaps `std::queue`). Every time you check, pop off the elements older than 360s and count the remaining ones.

If you check scarcely but update often, you might want to add the "popping" to the update itself, to prevent the set from growing too big.

Comment: Likely to be efficient if and only if the flag `value` is false most of the time.

Comment: @BenVoigt It's pretty hard to talk about efficiency without information about that, admittedly. That being said, it's what the OP asked about: a solution not using an array of booleans.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  Use the fact that `numberOfOccurrences(0,360)` and `numberOfOccurrences(1,361)` have 359 common terms.  So remember the sum, calculate the common term, and calculate the new sum.

```
void update(bool value)
{
    if (index >= 360)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    // invariant: count reflects t-360...t-1
    if (active[index]) count--;
    // invariant: count reflects t-359...t-1
    active[index] = value;
    if (value) count++;
    // invariant: count reflects t-359...t

    index++;
}
```

(Note that the if block resetting `index` removes the need for the modulo operator `%` so I removed that)

Another approach would be to use subset sums:

```
subsum[0] = count(0...19)
subsum[1] = count(20...39)
subsum[17] = count(340...359)
```

Now you only have to add 18 numbers each time, and you can entirely replace a subsum every 20 seconds.

Comment: Yes this is much more efficient in terms of processing , is there way we can improve this also in terms of memory, since active array size may huge if I need to track this for long time not just 360 seconds

Comment: Only if you query only every k seconds (use a subsum for each chunk of k) or accept an approximation